# How to use \widetext in jpsj3.cls?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, two-column

I have to write a paper  using the  [jpsj3.cls](http://journals.jps.jp/page/jpsj/authors/style) document class.
This style is two column in default.

In my paper, some equation are long, so I want to use `\widetext`.
But it seems  I cannot use it in `jpsj3.cls`.

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  Please post a minimal document that shows your problem. The document should be compilable and just show one long equation and probably not much else.  Then people will be better able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

My question is solved myself.

I have to add

`\usepackage{widetext}`

in preprint. And we can use \widetext

Comment: You shouldn't use `kantlipsum`. That is just for creating 'dummy' text in an example. It should almost never be loaded in a regular document, especially a journal article.

Comment: Unless you're Alan Sokal.

Comment: Do you mean \usepackage{widetext} is enough to use \widetext? I do not understand the meaning of kantlipsum. It is not needed?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You just need `\usepackage{widetext}`.  And unless you know what any package does, it's best not to use it. In this case `kantlipsum` produces random text that is supposed to be in the style of Immanuel Kant. This can be useful if you need some text to demonstrate a problem, but otherwise has no regular purpose.

Comment: Thank you. I will edit it. I didn't understand it because I am not good at English.